# Instead of 1 and 0, make display say On or Off

Tags: serial, c++, lcd, button, debounce

So for my project, I am making a button that turns on and off an LED, but also display the state of the led on an LCD and by Serial.  But my issue is, I don't want it to just show a 0 or a 1, I want it to say On or Off.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int inPin = 22;         // the number of the input pin
int outPin = 13;       // the number of the output pin

int state = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin

// the follow variables are long's because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long time = 0;         // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounce = 200;   // the debounce time, increase if the output flickers


void setup(){
    // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    // Print a message to the LCD.
    lcd.print("System Activated");
    //
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Ready...");

    pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(outPin, OUTPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("System Activated");
    Serial.println("Made by Mateo Holguin");
    Serial.println("0 = Light is Off | 1 = Light is On");
    Serial.println("=======================================");
}

void loop(){
    reading = digitalRead(inPin);

    if (reading == HIGH && previous == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {
        Serial.println("Button Switch State Change:");
        if (state == HIGH)
            state = LOW;
        else
            state = HIGH;

        Serial.println(state);
        Serial.println("");
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("State: ");
        lcd.print(state);

        time = millis();    
    }

    digitalWrite(outPin, state);

    previous = reading;
}
```

Comment: Both of these 2 answers works well, I just used the second one as I am a bit of a noob so I used one that I can understand more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option: use the "inline" *if* construct:

```
lcd.print(state ? F("On") : F("Off"));
```

The format is:

```
<if comparison> ? <true result> : <false result>
```

Note the use of `F(...)` to force the strings to stay in flash memory.

Comment: I am going to try this option as well, as it makes a lot of sense to me.  Thank you very much!

Comment: When I use that line I get " '_F' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @MateoHolguin Sorry, wasn't thinking straight that day - it's `F()` not `_F()`

Comment: I uploaded it to the Arduino, and it works perfectly the way I needed it to! Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

Put the strings to display in an array, and output them instead.

```
char const * const stateDisplay[] = {"Off", "On"};

 ...

lcd.print(stateDisplay[state]);
```

Comment: Could you please explain why "const" is used twice there? I've never seen that before and don't know how to look it up.

Comment: @Jerry: One is for `stateDisplay` (i.e. the pointer is constant), and the other is for `*stateDisplay` (i.e. the contents are constant as well).

Comment: Thanks! I can actually use that in a sketch I'm working on now.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I can finally get that one issue fixed!